# Open rolling log file while being written to

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

Can anyone point me at an application to display/view a rolling log file as it is being written to?

I know there are apps out there, but googling just gives me questions about writing to/creating the logs.
[This is Windows, not Unix]

Comment: I've tried Powershell:  "get-content c:\log\logfile.log -Wait" but this doesn't appear to update dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php).

There is a free version if you don't mind a small delay while it displays the splash screen or you can pay $25 to remove the delay or $35 for BaretailPro which also allows you to search the log files.

I use BaretailPro on my own machine and the free version of Baretail if I am working on a customer's computer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) tool, with follow option.

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -f /path/to/log
```

will show the last 10 or so lines of the log and then show you any new lines written to the log as they are written

Answer (score 0):

[Log4View](http://www.log4view.com/) can do that but it is commercial. Another idea would be to configure a UDP appender, then you can use [log2console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, there is a View -> Monitoring (tail -f) option that will continuously update the file for you.